# CSS 100% height in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, height

Why does `height:100%` not work in **IE**. How can we get around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
* html .class{ height:100% }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set height:100% to all the parents up to body. Try this (it works):

```
`<html><body style="height:100%;"><div style="height:100%;background-color:red">Here it is!</div></body></html>`
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AdnQ5/ doesn't look like it works to me.

Comment: "to all the parents up to body" - tried with `html`  too, now it works :-) http://jsfiddle.net/k7ScE/

Comment: @Bojangles does not work in IE.