# XHTML CSS background not filling entire div

Tags: css, xhtml

I've got a page that has a background color for the main container, but for some reason, the color ends just below the header div. The page and the CSS validate in the w3 validators, though, and I have no idea why and I've tried several different fixes.

CSS

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #e5e5dc;
    color: #000;
}

#maincontainer{
    background-color: green;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#topsection{
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#logo{
    background-image: url();
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#contentwrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#contentcolumn{
    margin-right: 230px; /*Set right margin to RightColumnWidth*/
}

#rightcolumn{
    float: left;
    width: 230px; /*Width of right column in pixels*/
    margin-left: -230px; /*Set left margin to -(RightColumnWidth) */
    background-color: transparent;
}

#footer{
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.innertube{
    margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
    margin-top: 0;
}

.error{
    background-image: url("images/misc/scroll.jpg");
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a:link, a:visited{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

EDIT -- Raw html source straight from view source in my browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Haven &bull; Login</title> 
    <link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 


    <script src="includes/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function init()
    {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = 'includes/all.js';
        document.getElementById('script_insertion').appendChild(e);
    }
    </script> 
</head> 
<body onload="init();"> 
<div id="script_insertion"></div> 
<div id="maincontainer"> 
    <div id="topsection"> 
        <div class="innertube"> 
            <h1>IMG</h1> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="contentwrapper"> 
        <div id="contentcolumn"> 
            <div class="innertube"> 
                <form action="./login.php?mode=login" method="post"> 
                    <table> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td>Username:</td> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="10" title="Username" /></td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td>Password:</td> 
                            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="10" title="Password" /></td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td> 
                            <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td> 
                        </tr> 
                    </table> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" /> 
                </form> 
                <br /> 
                Don't have an account yet? <a href="./register.php">Register here!</a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>  <div id="rightcolumn"> 
        <div class="innertube"> 
            Chat
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you include the php scripts in the example? CSS is for dealing pure html only- if you know that, then it would seem that you are dumping your work on someone... + the question is not even tagged under php- so it shouldn't contain php!
Please isolate the html in question...

Comment: @erric The question was in reference to the CSS and HTML that was posted. Just because There were instances of PHP means my question can't be answered? I left them in there so people could see the entire code, as sometimes, one misplaced tag is all it takes. I don't know "the html in question". It could be anywhere in that block of code, but I see absolutely nothing wrong with the syntax, personally

Comment: Your question is about HTML and CSS rendering in the browser. PHP has nothing to do with it. Show us the rendered HTML...not the PHP.

Comment: Edited the post. still validates on w3 and no errors in firebug. It also happens in both firefox and chrome, so it's not one of those "IE being itself again" things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are floating `#contentwrapper` which takes it out of the document flow so `#maincontainer` no longer contains it.

To contain it, you need to give `#maincontainer` an overflow attribute (auto should work).

FYI, adding borders to your elements are a good way to debug things like this.

Comment: I thought it might be worth adding this link to the answer - it is a great rundown of the `float` element. [http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a well addressed question. See [CSS 100% height in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954147/css-100-height-in-ie) or http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. My problem is that even when there is content that fills the entire page, the color that is set for the maincontainer div only flows to the end of the topsection div