# Height is 100%?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I will a style of asp.net webpage like:

```
body
    {
        font-family: Times New Roman, Serif;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        min-height:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    #container
    {
        /*background-color: #00CCFF; */
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #header
    {
        /* background-color: #FF00FF; */
        width: 100%;
        height: 95px;
        background-image:url('../Images/Back_logo.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-color:Transparent;
    }
    #menu
    {
        /*background-color: #FFFF00; */
        height:40px;
    }
    #left
    {
        /* background-color: #00FF00; */
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    text-align:left;
        border:1px solid #C8E3F1;
        background-color:#EEFFFF;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #center
    {
        width: 79%;
        float: right;
        /* background-color: #FF0000; */
    }
    #footer
    {
        /*background-color: #008000; */
        clear: both;
        height:70px;
        margin-top:10px;
        background-image: url('../Images/footer.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-color:Transparent;
    }
```

I have a problem is the height of page **not 100%**. I used min-height or height is 100% in **body**, but don't work. The **footer** change by the long of content **center**. How to fix?
The html is very simple:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="layout.master.cs" Inherits="layout" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Layout</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="App_Themes/theme1/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="container">
        <div id="header">HEADER</div>
        <div id="menu">MENU</div>
        <div id="left">LEFT</div>
        <div id="center">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">FOOTER</div></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In other pages use this Master Page, the div have ID is **center** can stretch or shrink belong to the contain in it. So that the display of footer isn't exact.

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954147/css-100-height-in-ie

Comment: I still have a problem that the footer must always below the center contain,that can changes the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML, Body

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
```

}

```
 #footer
{
    /*background-color: #008000; */
    clear: both;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;      
    margin-top:10px;
    background-image: url('../Images/footer.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:Transparent;
}
```

We need to give 100% height to both the html and the body tag. This is often overlooked but is vitally important as no element will adjust to a percentage height unless it knows what it’s parent height is currently occupying. As the container is a descendant of the body tag which is a descendant of the html tag, then this is required.

100% height is one of those things CSS doesn’t do so easily. When you specify an element to have a height of 100%, the 100% refers to the containing element’s height. The containing element would then need to be 100% the height of its containing element and so on. The trick is to set the height of the outermost elements to be 100%

Comment: And the footer,how to fix it at the bottom of the screen if the center isn't enough long, and it drag to fix if the center div is longer than the height of screen??

Comment: You can play with it, using many technique, for example. set the position of the footer to absolute and bottom:0px;  there are many other ways.

Comment: If set the footer to absolute, it don't work right when the center contain is longer than the height screen.The footer can't always below the contain. I used fixed position, but don't work too.

Comment: Please post your html code too, then i will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Put `html { height: 100% }` at the beginning and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the height is set to 100% in every point of your Xpath layout hierarchy. That is html->body->form->div id="center"

style="height:100% "

You can then continue using style="height:100% " in the child pages that will inherit from ContentPlaceHolder2 at the inheriting content place holder.

There are areas you might need to adjust(lower) the % height to allow other elements to fit in the area e.g. the other div s.