# Height 100% not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I know there are many questions about this and I have looked at all of them. I have a site where I need the left `<td>` to extend by 100%. I have all the containing blocks set to 100% and this works great in chrome and safari. However it does not extend to the base of the screen in IE or Firefox. I have a rough sketch of it here since the code is too long to paste. I have also included the css in the page to make it easier to view.

I used these two posts but neither has fixed my issue.
[CSS 100% height in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954147/css-100-height-in-ie)
[Div 100% height works on Firefox but not in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172918/div-100-height-works-on-firefox-but-not-in-ie-what-to-do)

Am I missing a container or is there a special way to make this happen in IE and Firefox? This is my first time messing with 100% height in css.

Comment: the site looks the same to me in firefox and ie. can you add a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: ahh ok chrome shows me what you mean.

Comment: @Bobo I see that I accidentally tested it in Mozilla with my pixel set code. It doesn't work in Firefox either :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of this line of css in td.left:

display:inline-block;

Remove it so it stays the default: display:table-cell. Then it works in IE.

I strongly encourage you not to use tables for this sort of layout though. Here's a good tutorial that will show you how to do this using divs+css: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: Default for td is `display:table-cell`. But you are correct. Also, IE and Firefox are correct. Chrome's implementation is the broken one.

Comment: Oops. You're right. Interesting note about Chrome's non-standard implementation here too.

Comment: I have no idea why I even had that in there....I think its because I changed from a div to a table and didn't edit the css. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is wrapping both panels with a bigger absolute DIV and that way you can give the inner div a (working) style like this:

```
height: 100%;
```

I've made an example here:

Result - http://fiddle.jshell.net/E8SK6/1/show/

Code - http://jsfiddle.net/E8SK6/1/